# PHP 'Upload File' code not working

Tags: php, file-upload

HTML in 'index.php':

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="application/pdf, .pdf" required><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">

</form>
```

PHP in 'index.php':

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $target_dir = 'docs/';
        $temp_loc = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"];

        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_loc,$target_dir.$file)) {
            ?><script>alert('successfully uploaded');</script><?php
        } else {
            ?><script>alert('error while uploading file');</script><?php
        } 
    }

?>
```

The following code doesn't seem to upload any of the documents I select to the target dircetory, that is, '/docs'.

I'm using wampserver with localhost, if that is needed at all. The 'file-upload' is allowed in the 'php.ini'

I've seen many tutorials and have even done troubleshooting on Stackoverflow itself, but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use error reporting

Comment: Try to define absolute path for $target_dir

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @Ace_Gentile Example?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display.

Comment: Try to print $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] variable and see what is the basic path like, then if it's correct do something like $target_dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/docs" and check if that folder exists and has correct writing permissions (I am supposing that your /docs folder is in your root. If not, add the missing part to the desired path. Your absolute path should look like /var/www/stuff/whatever/docs

Comment: If the doc folder is in root, you can also try to write like this $target_dir = './docs/';